# How to get started with Microsoft PixelSense

Tags: wpf, pixelsense

If I wanted to get a pilot project off the ground using Microsoft PixelSense, where or who do I ask for testing hardware?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a great interview [you should listen to](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=389).

Basically, you will likely need to purchase a PixelSense machine. The Developer edition is $15,000.  At the moment, it is difficult to get your hands on the bits unless you went to PDC but I'd imagine that will change and there will more opportunities in the future.

There is a simulator, but it was only available to attendees to PDC.  One of the input methods was to use TWO mice, if I recall correctly.  It looks like an interesting experiment, we'll see if it actually takes off.

As for the hardware, you can <strike>[buy it here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/pixelsense/purchaseprocess.aspx)</strike>. edit: [now here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/pixelsense/purchaseprocess.aspx)

To just test drive the actual unit, head down to Vegas and [see the unit in Harrah's](http://video.msn.com/video.aspx?mkt=en-us&vid=c6aa3288-f623-44b7-a4e4-7ff176f3d89e) casino.

Comment: Thanks. Dead link. New link here:  http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en/us/Pages/HowToBuy/HowToBuy.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Also, you could watch the PDC Video about developing for the Surface platform.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to start with the [official Microsoft page](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/developing.html) for developers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the link to what I think Bruno is also referring to
[**Developing for Microsoft Surface**](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/PC17/)

A pretty cool demo. AFAIR there is some talk of a simulator for the surface hardware although I'm not sure if it's free or part of the SDK.
The hardware units are available for sale in the US and everyone at PDC got the SDKs I think.. dunno if it'll be available for the general dev audience soon. Can't find a download link anywhere.. maybe you need to buy the h/w to get your hands on it..

Answer (score 0):

There's a book called "Developing for Microsoft Surface" that's been released. It's very basic but worth having a look.